# sql error 04098 invalid trigger

Tags: sql, oracle

I need some assistance with troubleshooting the trigger that I'm trying to create/use for logging updates and inserts on a table. 
I'm using a customers_history table to track all the changes being made on the customers table.

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
custID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
custFName VARCHAR2(30),
custLName VARCHAR2(30),
custState CHAR(20),
custZip NUMBER(5)
);
-- log inserts and updates on customers table
CREATE TABLE customers_history (
histID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
cID INTEGER, 
cFName VARCHAR2(30), 
cLName VARCHAR2(30), 
cState CHAR(20), 
cZip NUMBER(5)
);
```

Also, for the histID I'm using a sequence to auto increment the histID on customers_history table.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ch_seq
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_customers
BEFORE UPDATE 
OR INSERT ON customers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO customers_history(histID,cID,cFName,cLName,cState,cZip)
VALUES(ch_seq.nextval,:NEW.custID,:NEW.custFName,:NEW.custLName,
:NEW.custState,:NEW.custZip);
END;
/
```

I have been inserting two rows on customers prior to creating the trigger, and they work fine. After I create the trigger, it will not allow me to insert anymore rows on customers and it also throws the `ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.AUDIT_CUSTOMERS' is invalid and failed re-validation 04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"` error message.

I've tried to see if there is any code errors using `select * from user_errors where type = 'TRIGGER' and name = 'audit_customers';` and it returned no lines. Not sure if that helps or not. Thanks.

Comment: Why is the trigger being created in the `system` schema?  This seems suspicious.

Comment: @gordon linoff I'm running this all on a oracle db developer vm for a class, so all of our tables, triggers, etc are running on the system username.

Comment: @ gordon linoff Also, it would be a very stupid thing if I was asking for advice **on a public site** for code with malicious intent. Sorry to disappoint you man. Ha...

Comment: Try `select * from user_errors where type = 'TRIGGER' and name = 'AUDIT_CUSTOMERS';` (uppercase)

Comment: @PonderStibbons please read original post, final paragraph. What is the difference between the two statements? Thanks.

Comment: You wrote in this last paragraph 'audit_customers' and I think that it should be in uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

you have created your trigger for multiple `DML` operations (`Insert` and `Update`) so you need to specipy the `DML` operation by using `IF INSERTING THEN....END IF;` and `IF UPDATING THEN....END IF;` for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_customers
BEFORE UPDATE 
OR INSERT ON customers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF INSERTING THEN 
INSERT INTO customers_history(histID,cID,cFName,cLName,cState,cZip)
VALUES(ch_seq.nextval,:NEW.custID,:NEW.custFName,:NEW.custLName,
:NEW.custState,:NEW.custZip);
END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Why would this be necessary if the same code is being run for both operations?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think if he use `:OLD` he have to specify the operation because as you know the Insert Operation has not `:OLD`

Comment: I was intending on logging all of the inserts and updates on the same table if possible. I figured the same :new.object_type would work for both insert and update operations. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @JRW2252 . . . `:NEW` is defined for `insert` and `update`.  `:OLD` is defined for `update` and `delete`.

Comment: @JRW2252 yes the `:NEW` is the same for both, I thought you have used `:OLD` but I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

I went through and changed a couple things and it seems to work for both insert and update operations. I dropped the tables, sequence, and trigger, then did the tried the following code and it works now. Thank you all for your time and inputs!

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
custID INTEGER,
custFName VARCHAR2(30),
custLName VARCHAR2(30),
custState CHAR(20),
custZip NUMBER(5)
);
CREATE TABLE customers_history (
histID INTEGER,
cID INTEGER, 
cFName VARCHAR2(30), 
cLName VARCHAR2(30), 
cState CHAR(20), 
cZip NUMBER(5)
);
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_customers
BEFORE UPDATE 
OR INSERT ON customers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO customers_history(
histID,
cID,
cFName,
cLName,
cState,
cZip
)
VALUES(
ch_seq.nextval,
:new.custID,
:new.custFName,
:new.custLName,
:new.custState,
:new.custZip
);
END;
/
```

I used the same sequence code as before, added a couple of rows, and it worked. Then I altered the two tables, by adding the primary keys,

`ALTER TABLE customers ADD PRIMARY KEY(custID); 
ALTER TABLE customers_history ADD PRIMARY KEY(histID);`

inserted a couple other columns, modified a few rows, and it still worked. I'm a happy camper, although I'm not certain what or how it actually got fixed.